# Не строится диаграмма с использование Chart.js. Почему?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

```js
let button = document.querySelector('button');


button.onclick = function(){
    let wordsLength = [];
    let answer = prompt('Введи предложение');
    answer = answer.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "");
    let words = answer.split(' ');
    
    for (let i = 0; i < answer.length - 1; i++){
        let word = words[i];
        wordsLength.push(word.length);
    }
    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: words,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Количество букв',
                data: wordsLength,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>
        Запуск
    </button>
    <canvas id='chart'></canvas>
    <legend for="canvas"></legend>

    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на консоль браузера

> "TypeError: `word` is `undefined`"

Найдите место, где вы используете эту переменную. Обратите внимание на сам цикл. Изначально, вы разбиваете строку на слова, а потом делаете *цикл по длине строки*, и берете слова по этим индексам.

Если вы хотите в массив `wordsLength` записать длины слов, то надо и цикл делать по массиву `words`, либо просто ограничится такой записью:

```
let wordsLength = words.map(v => v.length);
```

```js
let answer = '123 1 asd qq'; //prompt('Введи предложение');
let words  = answer.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "").split(' ');

let wordsLength = words.map(v => v.length);


var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: words,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Количество букв',
            data: wordsLength,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<canvas id='chart'></canvas>
<legend for="canvas"></legend>
```